# Why my new protocol can only accept basic type in the method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.5

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol delegate <NSObject>

-(void)test:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

After I created a new protocol from xcode menu, i found i can't use `(NSString *)` type in my protocol method as the argument,but only the int and other basic type, the autocomplete function isn't working either.

why is that?

EDIT : 
maybe a picture can explain what i meant. please check here : http://sfault-image.b0.upaiyun.com/4a/cc/4acc50cc82e03404184c35c59c56cfcd_article

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us answer your question, please add some code showing us what you've tried already. This will help you get succinct, quick and relevant answers.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your project with the protocol in it? Does that fail, too, or is it just the auto-completion that's not working.

Comment: With protocol in it is fine. But if I put the protocol in a separate file,yea,the auto-completion is not working and all you can use is the primitive types like int,double... As the type of argument in the protocol.